# Solve the inequality $2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) } < 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

$2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) } < 1$

Let $2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) }-1=f\left( x\right)$

To find the values for which $f(x)<0$ I let $f(x)=0$:

$2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) }-1=0$

$2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) }=1$

$\ln \left( 2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) }\right) =\ln \left( 1\right) $

$\left( x^{3}-x\right) \ln \left( 2\right) =\ln \left( 1\right) $

$\left( x^{3}-x\right) =\dfrac {\ln \left( 1\right) }{\ln \left( 2\right) }$

$x^{3}-x=0$

$x\left( x^{2}-1\right) =0$

So $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=-1$

---

After testing values in intervals between those solutions I guess I lucked out and got the answer to be $f(x)<0$ on $\left( -\infty ,-1\right) \cup \left( 0,1\right) $

Although I got the write answer this time I'm not very confident in my ability to do so for other questions, is there a way to do this very "analytically" so you're absolutely sure of the answer and that it holds for all x in the given interval?
What tends to be general method? You find the values for which f(x) is zero and take values around that? Are there any tricks you can use? Thanks.

Comment: What is $2^0$?  And what happens for karger and smaller exponents?

Answer (score 4):

$2^{\left( x^{3}-x\right) } < 2^0 \Rightarrow x^{3}-x < 0$

And if the base of the exponent is $<1$ then the inequality gets reversed (you know why).

Comment: Neat, on this occasion this is valid, as we can make the bases the same, however what happens when  the bases aren't so neat? What tends to be general way of dealing with exponential inequalities?

Comment: $2^{x^3-x}<2^0 \Longleftrightarrow \log_2 2^{x^3-x}<\log_2 2^{0} \Longleftrightarrow x^3-x<0$. $m<n \Longleftrightarrow \log_2 m<\log_2 n$ was implicit. If the $2$ was $a$, shyamupa's answer remains valid for both $a>1$ and $0<a<1$, as having the base of an exponential be less than or equal to zero ($a\le 0$) doesn't "make sense", if we insist on having the numbers be in $\mathbb{R}$, or the real numbers. On $\mathbb{C}$ (complex numbers), $a^{x}=e^{x\ln a}$ and one has to choose one of several possible values for the complex logarithm $\ln a$ to be meaningful.